Why is import clr throwing an exception after pythonnet has been installed?
I am trying to access a .NET DLL from python using pythonnet. The dll contains a library that has been converted to .netStandard2. However, I am getting an error when simply trying to import clr. Can I have some guidance as to why I am unable to import clr and how to access the functions within the dll from python?
I am using Python 3.10.12
I have the following packages and their associated versions installed in my venv.
cffi 1.16.0
clr-loader 0.2.6
pip 23.0.1
pycparser  2.22
pythonnet  3.0.3
setuptools 65.5.0
This is my current mono version:
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notification:  kqueue
        Architecture:  arm64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        Interpreter:   yes
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        Suspend:       preemptive
        GC:            sgen

However, when I try to just run "import clr" it gives me the following error:
OSError: cannot load library '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib': dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib' (no such file).  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError: Failed to create a default .NET runtime, which would
                    have been "mono" on this system. Either install a
                    compatible runtime or configure it explicitly via
                    `set_runtime` or the `PYTHONNET_*` environment variables
                    (see set_runtime_from_env).

I have tried looking through documentation, etc. but am unsure how to work around this exception.
